# What is node:internal/process/promises:279 coming from sails lift

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm trying to launch sails lift on my back end on vs code and I keep getting this error. I want to know what it means and how to debug it.

```
node:internal/process/promises:279
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^
Error: write EPROTO 140704339895488:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (node:internal/stream_base_commons:94:16) {
  errno: -100,
  code: 'EPROTO',
  syscall: 'write'
}
```

I had to update my node from 16 to 19 and thought that would fix the problem but nothing changed.